# Rails - model relations from custom column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, relationship

Having an example of 2 models as follow:

Model 1

```
column 1 --- column 2 --- column 3 
id       --- fb_id    --- someOtherThing
```

Model 2

```
column 1 --- column 2 --- column 3 
id       --- fb_id    --- someOtherThing
```

Where for example, fb_id is the Facebook ID as big int.

How can I construct a relation (for example belongs_to) from column 2 of the first model to column 2 of the second model?

For the moment I have do something like this:

```
model 1:
belongs_to :model2, :foreign_key => 'fb_id'
```

But how can I pre-select the column from model 1 (column 2) that must match the second model's column? (I think that in this manner it takes column 1 from model 1).

**In synthesis:**
How to create a relation (`belongs_to` or `has_many`) `model1(:fb_id) => model2(:fb_id)`

and **not** `model1(:id) => model2(:fb_id)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you need is to retrieve a record with a valid association, right?

You can do that using the following:

```
Model1.joins(:model2 => :fb_id)
```

This will retrieve only the Model1' that have a valid association!

Comment: +1 for the helpful answer for who search for a valid association, but in my case I don't want to retrieve nothing, only have a good inter-model relations (I have update my post, maybe is more clear now ;))

Comment: Maybe would be better if you have a model for facebook_login with a polimorphic association to both of your models, 1 and 2

Comment: I don't know if I can do a polimorphic association in my case, it's more difficult that the example that I showed.